# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit - Provides in a package not working

Tags: 14.04, package-management, 64-bit, dpkg, 32-bit

I have recently switched over to 14.04 64bit from 12.04 32bit. 
I use packages that are built by my company and I have added architecture dependency in the sources.list file like:

```
deb [arch=i386] http:xxxxx
```

A lot of the packages are using the **Provides:** field in the *control* file in order to full-fill older dependencies. That has worked before on 32bit host machines but now it complains that the package is missing, f.e. I have a package **A** that provides **B** and when I install package **C** that depends on **B** it fails because it says **B** is not installed even though package **A** is properly installed.

The *control* file for package **A** has architecture defined as *all*.

Has this something to do with the architecture mismatch or what ?

Comment: To be more specific, then most of the packages in our repository are defined with **Architecture: i386** and it is those packages that are not playing well on 64bit machine.
How can I make sure that when using _apt-get_ to install a superpackage that should pull in the rest of the dependency tree will work with those packages defined as **i386** ? do I have to reconfigure those packages with **Architecture: all** and rebuild/publish them ?